# Create Hive Partitioned Table

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, create-table

How to create a table **T1** with partition **P1** and table **T2**'s columns?

```
create table T2(F1 int, F2 varchar(101), ..., FN date);

create table T1 as select * from T2 partitioned by (P1 int);
```

Error thrown:

> AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 1:undefined: ...2 as (select * from T1) partitioned by (P1 int) ^ Encountered: PARTITIONED Expected: LIMIT, ORDER, UNION CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error

Knowing this would be cumbersome:

```
create table T1 (F1 int, F2 varchar(101), ..., FN date) partitioned by (P1 int);
```

How could I achieve **T1**?

Comment: although it is cumbersome, you should follow the syntax in the second code snippet, [per the documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/DynamicPartitions)

Comment: There must be a better solution. **T2** could have been imported from an external DB, and the datatypes may have been converted to Hive data types. What would be a simple way to extract column name and column data type from **T2**?

Answer (score 0):

#### Static Partitioning

To perform this example, we have created a table “USER_DATA” with DATE_DT and COUNTRY as Partition columns. We will load data into “USER_DATA”.

Create Table Syntax:

```
CREATE [TEMPORARY] [EXTERNAL] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] [db_name.]table_name 
[(col_name data_type [column_constraint_specification] [COMMENT col_comment], 
[COMMENT table_comment] 
[PARTITIONED BY (col_name data_type [COMMENT col_comment], ...)];
```

Create Table Statement:

```
CREATE TABLE USER_DATA (USER_ID INT 
,USER_NAME STRING 
,SITE_DATA STRING) 
PARTITIONED BY (DATE_DT STRING,COUNTRY STRING) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
STORED AS TEXTFILE
```

#### 2. Dynamic Partitioning

To perform this example, we have created two tables “USER_DATA_DYN” and “USER_LOG_DATA”. Table “USER_DATA_DYN” will be a Partition table with column DATE_DT and COUNTRY as Partition column and table “USER_LOG_DATA” will be a non-Partition table. We will insert data in “USER_DATA_DYN” using the non-Partition table “USER_LOG_DATA”.

Create Table Syntax:

```
CREATE [TEMPORARY] [EXTERNAL] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] [db_name.]table_name 
[(col_name data_type [column_constraint_specification] [COMMENT col_comment], 
[COMMENT table_comment] 
[PARTITIONED BY (col_name data_type [COMMENT col_comment], ...)];
```

Create Table Statement:

Let us create the table “USER_DATA_DYN”.

```
CREATE TABLE USER_DATA_DYN (USER_ID INT 
,USER_NAME STRING 
,SITE_DATA STRING 
) 
PARTITIONED BY (DATE_DT STRING,COUNTRY STRING) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```